# selling ad space on android

Tags: android, admob, ads

Is there a mechanishm to sell ad space directly on android?
I know of admob and such, but on admob, you don't talk directly to the people whose ads show up in your app. 
If a service to do this does not exist, do you guys have any idea of how I could sell ads directly for my app?

Answer (score 2):

Both AdMob and AdWhirl support "house ads" where you can place your own text or banner ads into the rotation of ads.  By default AdMob is setup like Google's other advertising in that they do the brokering for you, and attempt to display the most relevant ads in your app.

House Ads would allow you to do direct ad sales and displays those ads directly in your app.  I am using AdWhirl and have sold ads to 3rd parties and backfill the rest with ads from Google.

Something to be aware of is that AdWhirl specifically states that their reporting for House Ads isn't exactly accurate.  So you may need to roll your own tracking mechanism if you do head that direction.

If you don't use a service like one of these from Google (or someone else) you'll have to roll your own ad service.

Comment: Is there a way to share ad reporting data in an official way? Like if I want to let the person who is buying ad space from me check their reports without giving them our account passwords.

Comment: Unfortunately not that I'm aware of at this point.  I am doing a CSV export and creating my own reports.

Comment: Sounds good, it seems like it would be best to simply create a shared admob account and sell ads by the hundred clicks, or something as accurate as what admob houseads can tell me

Comment: This might be a violation of the TOS as you are not allowed to communicate with advertisers directly, so I would check on that. These guys were doing the same thing and got suspended http://mobilemarketinglessons.blogspot.com/2011/04/step-by-step-guide-on-how-to-get.html